# Cannot center input field on View (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have View like this

Here is code

```
`<div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-8  " style="width: 1100px; ">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AdminLogin", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">

                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Пароль" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center" >

                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 15px;text-align: center;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Войти" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 200px;" />
                </div>

                <div  style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
                    <section id="socialLoginForm">
                        @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
                    </section>
                </div>
            }
        </section>
    </div>

</div>`
```

On local server is all ok

Here is Screen

[image]

But when I upload to server

it looks like this

[image]

I don't understand why so because I didn't change code?

**UPDATE**

Here is generated HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Логин - Видео Интервью</title>

    <script async type='text/javascript'>
        var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config)
        {
            function r(config){ t[config] = function(){ var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function(){ t[config].apply(t, i)})} }
            var t = { config:config},u=document,e=window,o='script',s=u.createElement(o),i,f;for(s.src=config.url||'//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js',u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s),t.cookie=u.cookie,t.queue=[],i=['Event','Exception','Metric','PageView','Trace','Ajax'];i.length;)r('track'+i.pop());return r('setAuthenticatedUserContext'),r('clearAuthenticatedUserContext'),config.disableExceptionTracking||(i='onerror',r('_'+i),f=e[i],e[i]=function(config, r, u, e, o) { var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o); return s !== !0 && t['_' + i](config, r, u, e, o),s}),t
        }({
            instrumentationKey:'a6c64876-3925-4b06-a0a7-fe91f4d5929a'
        });

        window.appInsights=appInsights;
        appInsights.trackPageView();

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="padding-left: 70px;">
    <p>
    <a href="/">
        <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="image" height="120px" width="120px">
    </a>
        </p>
</div>


<div class="navbar ">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="test12">
                <li ><a href="/Home/Contact">О нас</a></li>
                <li ><a href="/Home/Contact">Контакты</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/Account/Register" id="registerLink">Регистрация</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Role" id="loginLink">Логин</a></li>
    </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container body-content">
    


<h2  class="registrationclass" style="text-align: center">Логин</h2>
<div style="width: 160px; border: 6px solid #ffcf00;; margin: 0 auto;">

</div>
<div class="row row-centered">
    <div class="col-md-8  " style="width: 1100px; ">
        <section id="loginForm">
<form action="/Account/AdminLogin" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="tP-rTMzcQ_Ik5buMcYjOdondv1_hIrxeLjOgG_e3xQt9M90R90iDNqItSaCLrmed6KvPIBqJQK0ZJ9w4wIl2EcR7Vc6x0VJ1VnYxCnMxNx81" />                <hr />
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">
                   
                   
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center">
                   
                    
                        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Пароль field is required." id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Пароль" type="password" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="Password" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center" >
                    
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Запомнить меня? field is required." id="RememberMe" name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="RememberMe" type="hidden" value="false" />
                            <label for="RememberMe">Запомнить меня?</label>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 15px;text-align: center;">

                    <input type="submit" value="Войти" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 200px;" />

                </div>
                <div  style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
                    <section id="socialLoginForm">
                        

<hr />
<form action="/Account/ExternalLogin" method="post">            <div id="socialLoginList">
                <p>
                        <button type="submit" class="zocial google" style="height: 35px; font-size: 16px;width: 180px;" id="Google" name="provider" value="Google" title="Log in using your Google account">

                            Google
                        </button>
                        <button type="submit" class="zocial facebook" style="height: 35px; font-size: 16px;width: 180px;" id="Facebook" name="provider" value="Facebook" title="Log in using your Facebook account">

                            Facebook
                        </button>
                </p>
            </div>
</form>


                    </section>
                </div>
</form>        </section>
    </div>
  
</div>


    <hr/>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2017 - Smart Solutions</p>
    </footer>
</div>
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=DilzeZuJxdbQsfc_JOwsWB4VFDhTPM73urYeggaKdL81"></script>

<script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=-g7cxTWQV6ve_iRyKtg7LoBytQltgj_w8zTNeaLaBc41"></script>

<link href="/Content/css?v=fYPwGViDmt6y-kpdK5MUhO65n_wno8NoVjnSj7kvIxA1" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=inCVuEFe6J4Q07A0AcRsbJic_UE5MwpRMNGcOtk94TE1"></script>


    <script src="/bundles/jqueryval?v=WhRmI8vUVF186UwYB1zRP7-DwJzqpKlt0JksOBJvolw1"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Share the generated HTML code.

Comment: Update code @Kumar_Vikas

Comment: Lol, why minus?

Comment: Just in your css set `.form-group input{display:inline-block};`

Comment: It could be a cache issue, server-side or client-side. You could try ctrl + f5

Comment: @Eugene In your HTML code, its aligned at the center. try clearing the cache once.

Comment: Thank's dude

All ok now. Write comment like answer and I will plus it @Autista_z

Comment: the code was useful so I plus the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in your css set

`.form-group input{display:inline-block};`